# How to $concat two fields inside a subdocument in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

Let us say I have this object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aec063380a7490014e88792"),
    "personal_info" : {
        "dialing_code": "+44",
        "phone_number": "67467885664"
    }
}
```

I need to concat the two values personal_info.dialing_code (+44) and phone_number (67467885664) into one. +4467467885664 and compare it to a value. I need to retrieve a specific record from the database that will match the said value.

**PROBLEM**

I am having trouble concatinating two fields inside a subdocument and I am receiving this error:

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "$concat only supports strings, not object",
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "$concat only supports strings, not object",
    "code": 16702,
    "codeName": "Location16702"
}
```

**ATTEMPT #1**

I have tried this:

```
UserModel.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$personal_info' },
        {$project: {
            concat_p: {$concat: [
                '$personal_info.dialing_code',
                '$personal_info.phone_number'
            ]} 
        }}
    ])
```

It is giving me an error as mentioned above and in result I cannot do a $match right after.

**ATTEMPT #2**

I also tried this:

```
UserModel.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$personal_info' },
        {$project: {
            p_dialing_code: '$personal_info.dialing_code',
            p_phone_number: '$personal_info.phone_number',
            concat_p: {$concat: [
                '$p_dialing_code',
                '$p_phone_number'
            ]} 
        }}
    ])
```

I have successfully took out the subdocument values one level however when I tried concatinating, it is producing me null values. This is the result I am getting:

```
{
        "_id": "5af0998036daa90014129d6e",
        "p_dialing_code": "+44",
        "p_phone_number": "13231213213244",
        "concat_p": null
    }
```

I know how to do it on the $match pipeline but I have no luck concatinating the values inside the subdocument. Clearly, I need to do this first before I can compare. Thanks

Comment: Two things that might be helpful: 1. `$unwind` is for arrays not for nested objects 2. First example works fine for your sample document. Perhaps you have some documents with different "schema" in your collection. Is that possible ?

Comment: The first example did not work even if I remove the `$unwind`. I have other documents inside the `personal_info` object. In the example, I just specifically get the dialing_code and phone_number for the sake of example. But inside it, yes I do have nested objects as well but I don't need to process that. Would that affect my query?

Comment: Btw, on "schema" design level, I did not explicitly define a string type for the field inside because I made it schema-less, i.e. `personal_info: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,`. Could that be the issue why I cannot get results?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have different types under `personal_info.dialing_code` and `personal_info.phone_number` fields. In your example `$concat` is applied to every document in your collection and that's why you're getting an exception since `$concat` strictly expects its parameters to be `strings`.

So it will be working fine for document posted in your question but will throw an exception for something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aec063380a7490014e88792"),
    "personal_info" : {
        "dialing_code": {},
        "phone_number": "67467885664"
    }
}
```

One way to fix this is to add `$match` condition before `$project` and use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) operator to get only documents having `strings` on those fields you want to concatenate.

```
db.UserModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $eq: [ { $type: "$personal_info.dialing_code" }, "string" ] },
                    { $eq: [ { $type: "$personal_info.phone_number" }, "string" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {$project: {
        concat_p: {$concat: [
            "$personal_info.dialing_code",
            "$personal_info.phone_number"
        ]} 
    }}
])
```